# Windows Batch : move folder using batch FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, move

**The objective:** make a batch file that when executed from windows contextual menu, will move the selected folder to another place. (I'm using shell-x program (github) to make the contextual menu, so you can just ignore that part)

**The code I have (not working):**

```
FOR /D %%G in (*) do MOVE "%%G" "W:\OUTPUTFOLDER\"
```

**Additional info:**
Windows 10 x64.
Shell-X just executes a batch to do the actions needed. It works as intended but the batch I'm doing doesn't seem to work for that particular action (move a variable FOLDER). It works great when moving files.
Its important to say that the folders will be variables. Its not always the same folders or the same locations with the exception of the OUTPUTFOLDER.

Can anybody help with this?

---

Comment: What is the current directory when the `for/d` is encountered? Insert `echo %cd%&pause` before the `for` to display it. This needs to be the selected directory.

Comment: Assuming your shell extension works when a directory or folder is selected in explorer, it will usually pass that as an argument to the batch file. If that is true, then changing `*` to `"%~1\*"` may work. Although I'd prefer to leave that, and add a line before it, `@PushD "%~1" 2>NUL || Exit`, and a line after it, `@PopD` instead.

Comment: @Magoo The problem is that this extension doesn't show the batch file executing, so I cannot debug :(

Comment: @Compo It didn't work saddly, and as said, I cannot see the output of the terminal.

Comment: So try `echo %cd%>c:\somewhere\somefilename.txt` then read the file...

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I found a rather complex way to achieve what I need.

`FOR %%a in (%1) do set MYDIR=%1
for %%f in (%MYDIR%) do set "myfolder=%%~nxf"
echo %myfolder%

FOR %%G in (%1) do robocopy %%G "C:\OUTPUT_FOLDER\%myfolder%" /S /CREATE /MOVE`

Sorry about the formatting but I don't know how to make it look right here.

Comment: Unfortunately, without knowing how your unnecessary software works, I cannot help you further with it without more specific information and actual output. I also have no idea, why you even need that type of software, when you can create context menu entries without the neeed to use anything not already built-in to the OS. With the above comment though, that looks like you could have just used ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%~1" "C:\OUTPUT_FOLDER\%~nx1" /S /MOVE```

Comment: @Compo thanks anyway, I just found the answer by myself and shared on the OP.

Comment: Please also note that my above example, and your own new commented version, does not perform the same task as that which you used in your question. I have also edited your question again to rollback your previous modification. Please do not put answers/solutions in the question itself. We have an answer area for such things.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   OK for others, figure out for yourselves. sorry.